# How to Begin Python Web Programming with WFastCGI + IIS + Python 3.4?

Tags: python, iis

As a complete python newbie who just completed the free lessons on codeacademy, I followed the instructions on [this Python wfastcgi 2.2 page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi) and sucessfully installed the python handler on IIS.

Then I created a python file (module) `my_app.py` as per the `web.config` with the following code (which I adapted from somewhere):

```
def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type','text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return ['Hello world!\n']
```

Upon navigating to the localhost site, IIS returns the following error:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 779, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 621, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_HANDLER'))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 594, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = handler()
TypeError: wsgi_app() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

**Question**:

1. How and what do I pass for the 2 function arguments?
2. Starting the module with a function does not seem like a good idea. Can I use a class instead? If so, how should I change my `web.config` on this line:

```
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="my_app.wsgi_app()" />
```

Comment: What do the last tree lines in error output mean?

Comment: You don't call the function, WSGI does, so you don't need to worry about what it passes. And Python is perfectly fine with having functions at the top level; there is no need for a class here. Finally, that code would not give that error; please post the actual code.

Comment: Oops you are right. There was a index.php messing up the default document processing I think. Updated the error.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses from that config value.

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation (if you haven't done so already) is to configure Failed Request Tracing in IIS. Then whenever your WSGI handler (i.e. my_app.wsgi_app) crashes during development IIS will generate a nice .xml file, that you can view in a browser, detailing exactly what happened, including the Python traceback, even if your IIS is ultimately configured to generate "500 - Internal server error" in this instance.

Next, as Daniel Roseman has already suggested, change

```
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="my_app.wsgi_app()" />
```

to

```
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="my_app.wsgi_app" />
```

in your web.config file and wfastcgi.py will be able to find and invoke your wsgi_app.

Finally, your wsgi_app as shown will (I believe) fail with a Python traceback as follows:

```
File "<the path to ...\python\pythonXX\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py on your system>", line 372, in send_response
raise TypeError("content must be encoded before sending: %r" % content)
TypeError: content must be encoded before sending: 'Hello world!\n'
```

The solution to this encoding problem is described in David Beazley's "Python: Essential Reference" in the section on wsgiref (page 541 in my copy). I would suggest you try the following:

```
def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
    status = "200 OK"
    headers = [("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")]
    start_response(status, headers)

    response = ["Hello world!\n"]

    return (line.encode("utf-8") for line in response)
```

Hope this helps.